# Does selenium grid runs only Selenium command or also code chunk from different library

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium-grid

I have done my automation in `Robotframework` and I am using many libraries like `Selenium2Library, Sikuli Library, HTTP Library, OS library and few more.`

When I am running test on `Selenium Grid`, it invokes the browser on node and runs those steps which are from Selenium.

However, it does not run commands from `Sikuli Library`. Is selenium grid capable of running keywords from different libraries?

Answer (score 2):

No, the selenium grid only works with selenium. The selenium grid is a server much like a web server. It listens for specific commands, and performs those commands. It will only respond to commands from selenium clients.

Answer (score 0):

When using [Sikuly](https://github.com/rainmanwy/robotframework-SikuliLibrary) in Robot Framework it is necessary to first setup the external sikuly server and then connect to it from Robot Framework. Typically this is a localhost connection, but connecting to an external host is also possible.

When using Selenium Grid, a connection is made to an anonymous node and thus the host to which the Sikuly server is runnning as well. Did a quick check in google and found that getting the hostname/IP of the running node from the hub is possible. Using the code example [here](http://kevinormbrek.blogspot.nl/2013/11/get-ip-of-grid-node-when-using.html) I think it should be possible to create a direct connection to the Sikuly server.